Mouse Hovering/Mouse Clicked over image p5.js
I am trying to create the experience of playing a hand drum. The idea is that the user picks up the drum mallet, hovers it above the drum, and if the user clicks again the drum plays the audio. Is this possible? I have found a lot of resources about shapes, specifically ellipses, but not a lot of information about images.
var drum, mallet;
var x, y, w, h; // Location and size
let dragging = false;
let rollover = false;
let img;
let vel;
let pos;

function preload(){
  
  strike = loadSound('HandDrum.mp3');
  drum = loadImage('handdrum2.png');
  mallet = loadImage('drumMallet.png');
  
 
  
}
function setup() {
  createCanvas(750, 500);
  

  //Dimensions for Moving Stuff
  x = 400;
  y = 100;
  w = 300;
  h = 300;


}

function draw() {
  
  background(220);
  
  tint(219,69,69,250);
  image(drum,125,95,400,400);
  tint(82,217,198);
  //image(mallet,350,100,width/2,height/2);
  
   
  if (mouseX > x && mouseX < x + w && mouseY > y && mouseY < y + 2) {
    rollover = true;
  } else {
    rollover = false;
  }
  // Adjust location if being dragged
  if (dragging) {
    x = mouseX + offsetX;
    y = mouseY + offsetY;
   
  }
  image(mallet, x, y, w, h);
  
}
 

function mousePressed() {

  if (mouseX > x && mouseX < x + w && mouseY > y && mouseY < y + h) {
    dragging = true;
    offsetX = x - mouseX;
    offsetY = y - mouseY;
  }
}
function mouseReleased() {
   //Quit dragging
   dragging = false;

}




Sure, it's possible. Do you have a particular technical question about your code? What problem are you having with it, if any? Please share any relevant errors or undesirable behaviors, along with the expected behavior. Thanks.

Unfortunately I can't provide a detailed answer at the moment, hence the comment.  You can manually handle events as you do to handle drag/drop. depending on how confortable you are with p5 libraries you can p5.play since it handles some of this logic for you. Regarding logic you need to handle mouse down both for dragging and dropping and banging the drum. How would you move the mallet away from one drum without an accidental audio trigger ? To keep logic and interaction simpler how about...

...having an icon at the bottom to toggle activating the mallet. Once it's activate it always follows the cursor and when clicking on the drum it plays the audio. (when you toggle the mallet off it resets position, doesn't follow the mouse).

I figured it out so I am posting my code in case anyone else is looking to solve something similar. If someone else has a more efficient way of solving this feel free to comment/share suggestions.
let drumSound;
let drumImg;
let volSlider;
let drumCircle;
let malletImg;
let drumMallet;
let offsetX, offsetY; 
let dragging = false;

function preload() {
  drumSound = loadSound('HandDrum.mp3');
  malletImg = loadImage('drumMallet.png');
  drumImg = loadImage('handdrum2.png');
}
function setup() {
  createCanvas(700, 500);
  
  drumSound.playMode('restart');
  volSlider = createSlider(0, 1, 0.5, 0.01);
  volSlider.position(130, 40);
  
  drumCircle = new Drumcircle(width/2 - 150, height/2 - 150, 300, 300);
  drumMallet = new DrumMallet(width / 2 +80, height / 2 - 220, 300, 300);
}

function mousePressed() {
  drumCircle.clicked(mouseX, mouseY);
  
    if (mouseX > drumMallet.x && mouseX < drumMallet.x + drumMallet.sizeX &&
      mouseY > drumMallet.y && mouseY < drumMallet.y + drumMallet.sizeY) {
    dragging = true;
    offsetX = mouseX - drumMallet.x;
    offsetY = mouseY - drumMallet.y;
  }
}
function mouseReleased() {
  dragging = false;
}

class Drumcircle {
  constructor(x, y, sizeX, sizeY) {
    this.name = 'DrumCircle';
    this.drumImg = drumImg;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.sizeX = sizeX;
    this.sizeY = sizeY;
  }
  
  display() {
    image(this.drumImg, this.x, this.y, this.sizeX, this.sizeY);
  }
  
  clicked(x, y) {
    let radialDistance = dist(x, y, width/2, height/2);
    if (radialDistance < 140 &&mouseX > drumMallet.x && mouseX < drumMallet.x + drumMallet.sizeX &&
      mouseY > drumMallet.y && mouseY < drumMallet.y + drumMallet.sizeY) {
      drumSound.play();
      print('play drum');
    } else {
      print('silence');
    }
  }
}
class DrumMallet {
  constructor(x, y, sizeX, sizeY) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.sizeX = sizeX;
    this.sizeY = sizeY;
  }

  display() {
    image(malletImg, this.x, this.y, this.sizeX, this.sizeY);
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(0, 24, 25);
  
  drumSound.setVolume(volSlider.value());
  
  let volText = 'Volume';
  textSize(12);
  fill(255);
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(2);
  text(volText, 85, 45, 70, 80);
  
   if (dragging) {
    drumMallet.x = mouseX - offsetX;
    drumMallet.y = mouseY - offsetY;
  }
  
  drumCircle.display();
  drumMallet.display();
}

